# What are the loop gain and the transfer function of this transconductance amplifier feedback circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, transconductance-amplifier

Related to my previous questions, I would like to know what the approach for determining the loop gain and transfer function of the circuit presented below is:

[image]

The circuit is highly simplified. The VCCS would in reality be a differential amplifier loaded by a current mirror and would have big input and output impedances. VG1 is meant to represent the unregulated input voltage of the regulator with a DC level and a significant AC ripple. V1 would also be a Zener voltage reference.

This representation is closer to the reality of the circuit:

[image]

For DC conditions I calculated the closed loop gain to be:

$$V_{o}=\frac{g_{m}(\beta + 1)(R_{1}+R_{2})}{1+g_{m}(\beta + 1) R_{2}}\cdot V_{ref}$$

Simplifying for

$$g_{m}(\beta + 1) R_{2}\gg 1$$

gives the usual

$$V_{out}=\left(1+\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}}\right)\cdot V_{ref}$$

For the low frequency closed loop gain / open loop gain the result is the same. I obtained it by breaking the loop, passivizing all DC sources and replacing the transistor with the small signal equivalent model.

I am almost certain I made some mistakes in my derivations.

**What is the correct approach?**

Comment: Question: Please, give some information about the voltages Vin and Vo (second diagram).

Comment: Vin is a 20V DC source with a 5Vpp AC ripple. Vo is the regulated output voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach for a (rough) loop gain calculation:

- The loop is opened at the base node of T2
- The voltage gain at the collector node of T2 is

  **G=v_c2/v_b2=-(1/2)gm_2 * r_load * 2=-gm_2 * r_load**. (the factor 2 results from the current mirror)
- The dynamic load resistance is **r_load=hie_7(1+gm_7 * R_e)** with **R_e=R1+(R2||r_in2)**
- Because of the voltage follower (T7) we can set **v_c2=v_e7** and the voltage v_f across the feedback resistance **r_f=(R2||r_in2)** can be found using the voltage division between r_f and R1.
- Therefore, the loop gain is **G_loop=G * [R2||r_in2]/[R1+(R2||r_in2)]**

Comment: I needed some time to run this in my head. If I understand correctly, you detach the loop at T2 and add a test voltage source at its base: v_b2. What I don't understand is why the loop gain is v_f / v_b2 and not v_out/v_b2. I know you are right, but it still puzzles me.

Comment: I have opened the loop at the base of T2 for applying a test signal.  To get the loop gain I must consider the other end of the opening as the loop output - and that is the voltage I have called v_f because this voltage is fed back to the base of T2.

Comment: I fully understand now. Thank you!